# How to make drop shadow lay on border on responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries, pseudo-class

I have a nice flow going on my site when you mouse over all the navigation areas, you will see a red text and red drop shadow, it is fluid throughout the site.

I noticed today on responsive view, the SKINS and TEMPLATE pages, the mouse over is falling below the border and looks bad. I would like for this to follow the same suit as the desktop site.

Since these are separating out into 5 individual boxes on mobile, I think this might have something to do with it.

I am not married to this mobile view on these tabs, so if it makes sense to change how they are displayed that I can do also.

I have messed with the margins on the drop shadow to no avail.

```
.gallery-menu-wrapper ul li {
    border: 6px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 6px 3px;
}
```

Web link

http://dagrafixdesigns.com/2019/industrial-darker/skins.html

Would prefer to try to keep it simple as maybe I am over looking a inset or - margin call, but also maybe a pseudo class call could work if all else fails?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the shadow of previous elements in the DOM to appear on top of the element after it on hover, add `position: relative; z-index: 1;` to `.tp-navigations .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus`

Comment: @MCoker I added your comment mark up to my code, and I don't see a change on scaling down, the mouse over drop shadow is falling under the border still.. The site on desktop view was and is perfect on mouse over, it is this mobile scale that is dropping down.         .tp-navigations .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
 color: #fc3c3b;
 background-color: transparent;box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 #fc3c3b;position: relative; 
         z-index: 1!important;}

Comment: Did you add it to the rule at line 206 in http://dagrafixdesigns.com/2019/industrial-darker/css/style.css? If so, I don't see it. Also, in the screenshot, that isn't your site navigation - are those the buttons you're talking about that have the problem? I assumed it was the buttons at the top of the page. The buttons in your screenshot look fine on the site to me.

Comment: Yes it is added to line 206 see screen shot  http://dagrafixdesigns.com/2019/industrial-darker/images/css.jpg    But no the top menu is fine as so is all the menus throughout the website...it is ONLY on mobile view....so view that SKINS link or TEMPLATE link on a phone or tablet and touch the square button....see how the drop shadow falls below the border??  I am trying to make it uniform and make the drop fall on top of the bottom border as it does throughout the site on desktop view.... hope this helps, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: But since that is NOT the target element area, that doesn't help and I will remove it now from that line 206 ...   the mobile responsive css call out for target area is this code  .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li {
    border: 6px solid #333;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 6px 3px;
}

Comment: Ah now I see it. Sorry, I was looking at this, where the bottom border doesn't show up because of the background of the current nav item - http://i.imgur.com/TFbI1GH.png

Comment: After line 21 in responsive.css, where you define the border for those links, add `.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li {
 position:relative;
 
}

.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:hover:after {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -6px; left: -6px; right: -6px;
 height: 8px;
 background: #fc3c3b;
 content: '';
}
.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:hover {
  box-shadow: none!important;
}`

Comment: @mcoker just seen this post, sorry it was hidden...ok great this puts this exactly where I wanted it and is really great. If I can ask one last fix to this code, is there anyway to make the action behave the same as it does through out the website? I added the transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s!important to the code as I thought that would make it work but it doesn't.??

Comment: To be clear once you hover it has a smooth delay drop and retract, whereas this fix is missing this action. I thought the transition code would fix it

Comment: @MC sorry just tested this code out on my phone and it "appears" now you have to hit each TAB twice to get it to respond, that isn't good of course. maybe it is just best to forget this and leave it?

Comment: @DA-G-GURU to mimic the technique used in your nav, you can try this `.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: -6px;
    right: -6px;
    height: 6px;
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s!important;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 #fc3c3b;
}`

Comment: @DA-G-GURU Or you can remove the current `li:hover:after` rule and define these 2 things `.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: -6px;
    right: -6px;
    height: 0;
    background: #fc3c3b;
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s!important;
}` and `.our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:hover:after {
    height: 6px;
}`

Comment: @DA-G-GURU yeah having to click on the element twice to get the behavior to work is what happens when you assign `:hover` actions in CSS to a non link item (like an `li`) then you also have some kind of JS click handler on it or an `a` as a child that also does something on click. It's generally not advised to do that because, like you said, people have to click on the thing twice.

Comment: @MCoker  I don't know how you know when I need help (maybe you can tag me or something) but your explanations and coding to me I follow better than anyone else to date. I really appreciate what you have done for me, as well as others. Please keep up the good work and I will revert this code back and call it a day on this  matter. Again a please MC. Cheers

Comment: @DA-G-GURU word! my pleasure :D

Answer (score 1):

When your navigation (`.gallery-menu-wrapper ul li`) responds down, responsive.css (line 21) adds a 6px border all around the element.

If you add a `border-bottom-width: 0px !important;` to your hover state it reverses this effect and the drop shadow lines up as expected.

Comment: That code just removed the bottom border on hover state, not what i am after. I did add the following code to the responsive css file and the drop did move up inside, however it is still to far north as i would like for hover state drop shadow to be exactly on TOP of the bottom border, like it does when viewing on desktop.                 .our-project .gallery-menu-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background-color: #2f2f2f ;
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 0 0 #fc3c3b inset;
    color: #fc3c3b;
    z-index: 2;
}

Comment: I just added to the code an INSET which made it hover inside instead of outside as you see by that code posted. it is close but not there yet if at all lol.

Comment: @DA-G-GURU - Yup, seen it. The problem is still with that border, it is only added to the individual elements when the page reduces down. The border on the bottom pushes your drop shadow down.

Comment: exactly right, is there anyway to fix this? I mean i can leave as is really if it is not fixable or a pain lol.

Comment: Let me run this by you, would a change in code for mobile view to target a bottom border on hover state work better or at all? Or what about a pseudo class after?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was out last night :)
I would just remove the bottom border, setting width to '0'. This puts the shadow where it should be, and you don't notice the fact that there isn't a border as the shadow covers it. Reducing this shadow to 6px, rather than 8, would also help (6 is the width of the border). Basically you're replacing the border with the shadow...

Comment: Thx will just leave as is and make the border 6 px...I am ok with this solution